# MVVM, Shared Model и паттерн Repository

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Имеется WPF MVVM приложение, отображающее геометрические фигуры (Shape) внутри полотна (Canvas).

Упрощенная версия для простоты изложения:

Модель:

```
class Canvas
{
    public List<Shape> Shapes;
}

class Shape
{
    public int X;
    public int Y;
}
```

Имеется несколько ViewModel'ей, некоторые из них отображают данные выбранной фигуры (фигура выбирается по клику на фигуру), некоторые - данные выбранного Canvas'а (выбирается с помощью комбобокса в ToolbarView), некоторые - и то и другое.

Т.о. имеется CanvasViewModel, CanvasPropertiesViewModel, ShapePropertiesViewModel , ToolbarViewModel.

ToolbarViewModel, CanvasViewModel и CanvasPropertiesViewModel связаны с текущим Canvas'ом.
ToolbarViewModel и ShapePropertiesViewModel связаны с выбранной фигурой.
ToolbarView, связанный с ToolbarViewModel, отображает большой плоский список названий всех canvas'ов.

**Вопрос 1: как шарить между ViewModel'ми выбранную фигуру и выбранный canvas?**
Пробовал через EventAggregator, но получается слишком много регистраций сообщений, код становится не читаемый.

**Вопрос 2: Кто должен отвечать за загрузку данных с сервера о canvas и его сохранение? И где лучше разместить эту логику (может как-то использовать Repository)?** (имеется сторонний web сервис, который отдает и сохраняет данные о canvas)

Comment: "как шарить между ViewModel'ми выбранную фигуру и выбранный canvas" сводится к "как шарить объект между разными классами" с понятными ответами. глобальный контекст, инъекция через конструктор, корневая VM, как хотите.

Comment: А зачем Вам вообще делать разные ViewModel? Вы можете все формы биндить к одной ViewModel и там, например, сделать свойство SelectedItemID, которое привяжете к комбобоксу или еще чему-то.

Comment: @potehin143 А это нормальная практика, чтобы связь View <-> ViewModel была не один к одному?

Comment: Если главная форма существует в единственном экземпляре, то почему бы нет. Это не нарушает паттерн, но упрощает синхронизацию. В конечном счете нужно смотреть конкретику Вашей задачи. Если она решается, то почему нет.  Быть может стоит биндить не все View Вашего приложения, но те, которые тесно связаны между собой.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Во-первых, если `Canvas` ещё как-то оправдано, то `ToolbarViewModel` — никак. Тулбар — это подробность View, а смысл этой VM — корневые параметры отображения.

Таким образом, у нас получается `class RootVM` с `ReadOnlyCollection<CanvasVM> Canvases` и DP `CurrentCanvas`. К которому легко прицепить комбобокс или там `ListView`.

Затем, я бы слил вместе `CanvasViewModel` и `CanvasPropertiesViewModel`, вроде бы они отвечают за одну и ту же сущность.

Давайте посмотрим, кому из ваших VM реально нужен `CurrentCanvas`. `ToolbarViewModel` содержит его. `CanvasViewModel` существует на *каждый* канвас, и знать о `CurrentCanvas` вовсе не должна. И `CanvasPropertiesViewModel` мы слили с `CanvasViewModel`.

Проблема исчезла!

---

Теперь, о загрузке/выгрузке с сервера. За это отвечают модельные объекты (по классу на Canvas и фигуру). Решение о загрузке-выгрузке принимает в любом случае бизнес-логика, так что это она должна командовать модели произвести обмен информацией. Ну и на VM лежит ответственность за синхронизацию данных с моделью.

---

Не бойтесь, чтобы одна VM отображалась в нескольких местах несколькими разными View, причём по-разному. Это нормальная практика.

Comment: хочу спросить "нельзя ли вас пригласить в чат на обсуждения многих спорных вопросов MVVM, если вы в этом разбираетесь"?

Comment: @vitidev: Можно, конечно, но я не эксперт, я могу лишь рассказать собственное мнение.

Comment: тогда вам сюда http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44712/vlad-and-vitidev-mvvmsmc 
как же неудобно тут все устроено. никаких уведомлений